# let app.use() wait untill connection to redis instance is made

Tags: node.js, express, redis, node-redis

I'm writing an express middleware function that depends on a redis store, to enable rate limiting. It works, but the problem is that I store my redis credentials in google cloud's secret manager. I need to do an **asynchronous** request to secret-manager, so there is a small delay on the state of the redis connection.

My function to connect with the redis instance returns a promise. When the promise is fullfilled, the redis connection is established.

```
'use strict'
// global variables for use in other functions as well
let globals = {}

// redis component where the connection with the redis instance is established
const Redis = require('./components/redis')

// connect is a promise
Redis.connect.then(conn => {
    // connection established
    globals.redis = conn
    // globals.redis contains now the connection with the redis instance
    // for use in other functions, this works
}).catch(err => console.log('could not connect with the redis instance')

// rate limiter function which depends on a redis instance
const RateLimiter = require('./components/rate-limiter')
const rateLimiter = RateLimiter({
    store: globals.redis,
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
    max: 5
})

app.use(rateLimiter)
```

This code will not work because app.use(ratelimiter) is executed **before** the redis connection has established. Moving the RateLimiter code **inside** the then()-function of the redis promises does not cause an error, but the app.use()-function does not work then.

My ideal solution would be:

```
// connect is a promise
Redis.connect.then(conn => {
    // connection established
    globals.redis = conn
    // globals.redis contains now the connection with the redis instance
    // for use in other functions, this works

    // <-- MOVING THE RATE LIMITER CODE INSIDE THE THEN()-FUNCTION
    // DOES NOT WORK / THE MIDDLEWARE IS NOT USED -->

    // rate limiter function which depends on a redis instance
    const RateLimiter = require('./components/rate-limiter')
    const rateLimiter = RateLimiter({
        store: globals.redis,
        windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        max: 5
    })

    app.use(rateLimiter)
}).catch(err => console.log('could not connect with the redis instance')
```

How can I let app.use() 'wait' untill there is a redis connection?

Answer (score 0):

You could setup redis in an async function and use async/await like this:

```
'use strict'
// global variables for use in other functions as well
let globals = {}

// redis component where the connection with the redis instance is established
const Redis = require('./components/redis')

async function setupRedis()
try {
    // connect is a promise
    const conn = await Redis.connect;
    // connection established
    globals.redis = conn
    // globals.redis contains now the connection with the redis instance
    // for use in other functions, this works

    // rate limiter function which depends on a redis instance
    const RateLimiter = require('./components/rate-limiter')
    const rateLimiter = RateLimiter({
        store: globals.redis,
        windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
        max: 5
    })

    app.use(rateLimiter)
} catch (error) {

    console.error("could not connect with the redis instance");
    // rethrow error or whatever, just exit this function
}


setupRedis();
```